# how can i get the program to raise no_data found for eno then check for sal>25000?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, triggers

I need to create a trigger If the salary is more than 25000/-
If empno of emp table exists and salary is less than 25000/- then update that salary to 25000/-

```
DECLARE  
emp_sal_not_morethan_25k Exception; 
PRAGMA exception_init( emp_sal_not_morethan_25k, -20001 ); 
 
v_eno emp.empno%TYPE; 
v_empname emp.ename%TYPE; 
v_sal emp.sal%TYPE; 
v_deptno emp.deptno%type; 
 
BEGIN 
 
v_eno:= 100; 

SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, SAL
into v_eno, v_empname, v_sal
FROM emp  
WHERE empno = v_eno ; 

exception when  NO_DATA_FOUND then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No Data found for Employee ID ' || v_eno); 


v_sal:= 32000; 
 
if v_sal>25000  then 
raise_application_error(-20001,'Salary Cannot be updated to more than 25000.'); 

update emp 
set sal = 25000 
where empno = v_eno; 
 
else 

update emp 
set sal = v_sal 
where empno = v_eno; 
 
end if; 
 
END; 
/
```

the following error i get:

```
ORA-20001: Salary Cannot be updated to more than 25000. ORA-06512: at line 26
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

the empno  i.e. v_eno is not triggering the no_data_found exception rather it triggers for sal>25000 before...

can someone please help me

Comment: `v_sal:= 32000; 
 
if v_sal>25000  then 
raise_application_error` What do you expect to be at this line? You raise an exception, that's why program terminates. If you need to set all the salaries greater than 25k to 25k, then use plain `update`: `update emp set salary = 25000 where salary > 25000`. No PL/SQL code required

Answer (score 1):

Your code, simplified (close to pseudocode):

```
SQL> begin
  2    select ... where empno = v_eno;
  3
  4  exception
  5    when no_data_found then
  6      if v_sal > 25000 then
  7         raise_application_error
  8      else
  9         update emp set
 10      end if;
 11  end;
```

- line #2: if there's no `EMPNO` equal to `V_ENO`, `NO_DATA_FOUND` is raised
- line #4: exception handling section takes over
- line #5: oh, great! You're handling `NO_DATA_FOUND`!
- line #6: so, what happens if `V_SAL` is greater than `25000`?

  - line #7: you're raising an exception
- line #8: what if `V_SAL` isn't greater than `25000`?

  - line #9: even better, update the table and set employee's new salary
- the end

Which means that answer to your question:

> the empno i.e. v_eno is not triggering the no_data_found exception rather it triggers for sal>25000

is that `NO_DATA_FOUND` actually **is raised**, but you "mis-handled" it with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` which is pretty much useless, it won't prevent the rest of code to be executed) there's plenty of code that follows; as salary is greater than `25000`, yet another exception is raised (your own `raise_application_error`).

Therefore, you might want to consider enclosing the 1st `select` statement into its own `begin-exception-end` block (lines #2, 4, 7):

```
SQL> begin
  2    begin
  3       select ... where empno = v_eno;
  4    exception
  5       when no_data_found then
  6          raise_application_error('Employee does not exist');
  7    end;
  8
  9    if v_sal > 25000 then
 10       raise_application_error
 11    else
 12       update emp set
 13    end if;
 14  end;
```

Comment: First I did like to thank you for your efforts. Thank You So much. I did the following changes it did work thankyou but I have one more demand i.e. I also need to update the employee salary to 25k if the salary mentioned is greater than 25k... the update in salary of emp table is not happening unfortunately

Comment: Update of the table in case of `no_data_found` looks at least strange. To update the table for this specific employee you either need an update with `where` clause or `select ... for update` to prevent updates between data retrieval and data processing